# JDI StackFrame.Location.lineNumber is missing. Is this due to missing debug information?

Tags: java, debugging, java-11, debug-information

I'm debugging a Java program within which a thread is suspended. When examining the stack trace of this thread, there is a JDI [StackFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html) whose method is `sleep` for the JDK class [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)). I want to examine the JDI Location of this StackFrame, particularly the [lineNumber](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/Location.html#lineNumber()) of this method. However, the lineNumber is missing and I wonder why. Is this because the JDK class I'm using was not compiled with debug information?

I see that methods defined by myself, compiled with debug information, have lineNumbers available which leads me to think that the presence of the debug information is the difference. However, I'm wondering if any other factors may be the issues. Are lineNumbers derived from debug information?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, line numbers are derived from [debug information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12) in the class file though there are some more possible reasons for the absence of line numbers. But the most likely case is that there are no line numbers in the class files…

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was trying to get a line number for a native method which has no function body (hence no line number).